# Implement CSS3 style for drag and drop angularjs after click a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, ionic-framework

I had done an Angularjs drag and drop method in my project. I do not have any problems in drag and drop, however I got problems on how to make style for draggable element after next action was taken.

For my case, if user drag *Goose* and *Rabbit* to box labelled *Animals that give birth*, the user will click the button *Check Answer*. There will be *Correct* or *Wrong* symbol above each draggble div.

I try to inspect the element, but I have seen only these styles:

```
[ng-drag] {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: #131313;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    cursor: move;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

The *ng-drag* directive was applied to each draggable element. How I can differentiate it each element and make it individual style? This thing was make me so confuse and need help from you all guys. Can anyone help me?

I do really appreciate for any suggestion or help.

My expected output:

[image]

Snippet for your reference:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp',['ngDraggable']).controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
  
    $scope.checkAnswer = function()
    {
      
    }

$scope.centerAnchor = true;
    $scope.toggleCenterAnchor = function () {
        $scope.centerAnchor = !$scope.centerAnchor
    };

    var onDraggableEvent = function (evt, data) {
        console.log("128", "onDraggableEvent", evt, data);
    };
    $scope.$on('draggable:start', onDraggableEvent);
    $scope.$on('draggable:end', onDraggableEvent);
    $scope.droppedObjects0 = [{name:'Goose'},{name:'Rabbit'},{name:'Chick'},{name:'Cat'}];
    $scope.droppedObjects1 = []; //Answer: Cat + Rabbit
    $scope.droppedObjects2 = []; //Answer: Chicken + Goose
    
    
    $scope.AnswerOject1 = [{name:'Arnab'},{name:'Kucing'}];
    $scope.AnswerOject2 = [{name:'Angsa'},{name:'Ayam'}];
    
    $scope.onDropComplete0 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("127", "$scope", "onDropComplete0", data, evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects0.indexOf(data);
        if (index == -1)
            $scope.droppedObjects0.push(data);
    };
    $scope.onDropComplete1 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("127", "$scope", "onDropComplete1", data, evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(data);
        if (index == -1)
            $scope.droppedObjects1.push(data);
    };
    $scope.onDragSuccess0 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("133", "$scope", "onDragSuccess0", "", evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects0.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects0.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    $scope.onDragSuccess1 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("133", "$scope", "onDragSuccess1", "", evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects1.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    $scope.onDragSuccess2 = function (data, evt) {
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects2.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects2.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    $scope.onDropComplete2 = function (data, evt) {
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects2.indexOf(data);
        if (index == -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects2.push(data);
        }
    };
    var inArray = function (array, obj) {
        var index = array.indexOf(obj);
    };
});
```

```css
.body
{
    width:500px;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
}

[ng-drag] {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

[ng-drag] {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: #131313;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    cursor: move;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

ul.draggable-objects:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}

.draggable-objects li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin:2px;
}

[ng-drag].drag-over {
    border: solid 1px red;
}

[ng-drag].dragging {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

[ng-drop] {
    background: rgba(198, 255, 198, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

[ng-drop].drag-enter {
    border: solid 5px red;
}

[ng-drop] span.title {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

[ng-drop] div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.list-of-drag-item
{
    height: 83px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngDraggable/0.1.10/ngDraggable.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="body">
Categorize the animals based on their reproductive system
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="list-of-drag-item" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete0($data,$event)">
            <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects0" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
                ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess0($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}">
               {{obj.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="col div-left">
        <span class="title">Animals that give birth
        <div ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete1($data,$event)">
            <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects1" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
                 ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess1($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}">
                {{obj.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col div-right">
        <span class="title">Animals that Laying Eggs</span>
        <div ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete2($data,$event)">
            <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects2" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
                 ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess2($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}">
                {{obj.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div style="text-align:center">
      <button ng-click="checkAnswer()">Check Answer</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to add some logic to your check answer function, which actually checks the answer and assigns a boolean:
<sub>(In my example I'm just alternating between true and false)</sub>

```
var i = 0;
$scope.checkAnswer = function() {
  $scope.droppedObjects1.concat($scope.droppedObjects2).forEach(function(x) {
    x.correct = (i++ %2) === 0;
  });
}
```

Then use this "correct" field to apply an appropriate class:

```
ng-class="{ correct: obj.correct === true, wrong: obj.correct === false }"
```

Then style the two classes how you want them to look:

```
.correct .wrong { 
    position: relative;
}
.correct:before, .wrong:before {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 6px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:-20px;
    right:-15px;
    font-size:30px;
}
.correct:before {
    content:'\2713';
    color:green;
}
.wrong:before {
    content:'x';
    color:red;
}
```

---

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp',['ngDraggable']).controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
  
var i = 0;
$scope.checkAnswer = function() {
  $scope.droppedObjects1.concat($scope.droppedObjects2).forEach(function(x) {
    x.correct = (i++ %2) === 0;
  });
}

$scope.centerAnchor = true;
    $scope.toggleCenterAnchor = function () {
        $scope.centerAnchor = !$scope.centerAnchor
    };

    var onDraggableEvent = function (evt, data) {
        console.log("128", "onDraggableEvent", evt, data);
    };
    $scope.$on('draggable:start', onDraggableEvent);
    $scope.$on('draggable:end', onDraggableEvent);
    $scope.droppedObjects0 = [{name:'Goose'},{name:'Rabbit'},{name:'Chick'},{name:'Cat'}];
    $scope.droppedObjects1 = []; //Answer: Cat + Rabbit
    $scope.droppedObjects2 = []; //Answer: Chicken + Goose
    
    
    $scope.AnswerOject1 = [{name:'Arnab'},{name:'Kucing'}];
    $scope.AnswerOject2 = [{name:'Angsa'},{name:'Ayam'}];
    
    $scope.onDropComplete0 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("127", "$scope", "onDropComplete0", data, evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects0.indexOf(data);
        if (index == -1)
            $scope.droppedObjects0.push(data);
    };
    $scope.onDropComplete1 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("127", "$scope", "onDropComplete1", data, evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(data);
        if (index == -1)
            $scope.droppedObjects1.push(data);
    };
    $scope.onDragSuccess0 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("133", "$scope", "onDragSuccess0", "", evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects0.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects0.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    $scope.onDragSuccess1 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("133", "$scope", "onDragSuccess1", "", evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects1.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    $scope.onDragSuccess2 = function (data, evt) {
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects2.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects2.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    $scope.onDropComplete2 = function (data, evt) {
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects2.indexOf(data);
        if (index == -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects2.push(data);
        }
    };
    var inArray = function (array, obj) {
        var index = array.indexOf(obj);
    };
});
```

```css
.body
{
    width:500px;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
}

[ng-drag] {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

[ng-drag] {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: #131313;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    cursor: move;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

ul.draggable-objects:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}

.draggable-objects li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin:2px;
}

[ng-drag].drag-over {
    border: solid 1px red;
}

[ng-drag].dragging {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

[ng-drop] {
    background: rgba(198, 255, 198, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

[ng-drop].drag-enter {
    border: solid 5px red;
}

[ng-drop] span.title {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

[ng-drop] div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.list-of-drag-item
{
    height: 83px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.correct .wrong { 
    position: relative;
}
.correct:before, .wrong:before {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 6px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:-20px;
    right:-15px;
    font-size:30px;
}
.correct:before {
    content:'\2713';
    color:green;
}
.wrong:before {
    content:'x';
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngDraggable/0.1.10/ngDraggable.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="body">
Categorize the animals based on their reproductive system
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="list-of-drag-item" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete0($data,$event)">
            <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects0" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
                ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess0($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}">
               {{obj.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="col div-left">
        <span class="title">Animals that give birth
        <div ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete1($data,$event)">
            <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects1" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
                 ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess1($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}"
                 ng-class="{ correct: obj.correct === true, wrong: obj.correct === false }">
                {{obj.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col div-right">
        <span class="title">Animals that Laying Eggs</span>
        <div ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete2($data,$event)">
            <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects2" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
                 ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess2($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}"
                 ng-class="{ correct: obj.correct === true, wrong: obj.correct === false }">
                {{obj.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div style="text-align:center">
      <button ng-click="checkAnswer()">Check Answer</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That bug I can cater with another logic.

Comment: @lamelemon,  The business logic of deciding which answers are correct is down to the OP to decide for himself.

Answer (score 3):

1. Added information inside the original data - where is the good-box of each of the objects.
2. Once drop - check if dropped in the correct box and added good/bad classname to the dropped item.
3. On click on the `check answer` - add/remove the `reveal` class on the `body` element and once added - using css and the value from #2 - the boxes have the relevant color (green/red).

You can use this example to add some other html (V/X) inside the dropped box.

Here is the working snippet:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp',['ngDraggable']).controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
  
    $scope.checkAnswer = function()
    {
      if (angular.element('body').hasClass("reveal")) {
        angular.element('body').removeClass("reveal");
      } else {
        angular.element('body').addClass("reveal");
        }
    }

$scope.centerAnchor = true;
    $scope.toggleCenterAnchor = function () {
        $scope.centerAnchor = !$scope.centerAnchor
    };

    var onDraggableEvent = function (evt, data) {
      console.log("128", "onDraggableEvent", evt, data);
    };
    $scope.$on('draggable:start', onDraggableEvent);
    $scope.$on('draggable:end', onDraggableEvent);
    $scope.droppedObjects0 = [{name:'Goose', goodbox: '2'},{name:'Rabbit', goodbox: '1'},{name:'Chick', goodbox: '2'},{name:'Cat', goodbox: '1'}];
    $scope.droppedObjects1 = []; //Answer: Cat + Rabbit
    $scope.droppedObjects2 = []; //Answer: Chicken + Goose
    
    
    $scope.AnswerOject1 = [{name:'Arnab'},{name:'Kucing'}];
    $scope.AnswerOject2 = [{name:'Angsa'},{name:'Ayam'}];
    
    $scope.onDropComplete0 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("127", "$scope", "onDropComplete0", data, evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects0.indexOf(data);
        if (index == -1)
            $scope.droppedObjects0.push(data);
    };
    $scope.onDropComplete1 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("127", "$scope", "onDropComplete1", data, evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(data);
        if (data.goodbox == 1) {
          data.class = 'good'
        } else {
          data.class = 'bad'
        }
        if (index == -1)
            $scope.droppedObjects1.push(data);
    };
    $scope.onDragSuccess0 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("133", "$scope", "onDragSuccess0", "", evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects0.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects0.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    $scope.onDragSuccess1 = function (data, evt) {
        console.log("133", "$scope", "onDragSuccess1", "", evt);
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects1.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    $scope.onDragSuccess2 = function (data, evt) {
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects2.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects2.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    $scope.onDropComplete2 = function (data, evt) {
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects2.indexOf(data);
        if (data.goodbox == 1) {
          data.class = 'good'
        } else {
          data.class = 'bad'
        }
        if (index == -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects2.push(data);
        }
    };
    var inArray = function (array, obj) {
        var index = array.indexOf(obj);
    };
});
```

```css
.body
{
    width:500px;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

[ng-drag] {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

[ng-drag] {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: #131313;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    cursor: move;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.reveal [ng-drag].good {
  color: green;
}
.reveal [ng-drag].bad {
  color: red;
}
ul.draggable-objects:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}

.draggable-objects li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin:2px;
}

[ng-drag].drag-over {
    border: solid 1px red;
}

[ng-drag].dragging {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

[ng-drop] {
    background: rgba(198, 255, 198, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

[ng-drop].drag-enter {
    border: solid 5px red;
}

[ng-drop] span.title {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

[ng-drop] div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.list-of-drag-item
{
    height: 83px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngDraggable/0.1.10/ngDraggable.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="body">
Categorize the animals based on their reproductive system
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="list-of-drag-item" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete0($data,$event)">
            <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects0" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
                ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess0($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}">
               {{obj.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="col div-left">
        <span class="title">Animals that give birth
        <div ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete1($data,$event)">
            <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects1" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
                 ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess1($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}" class="{{obj.class}}">
                {{obj.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col div-right">
        <span class="title">Animals that Laying Eggs</span>
        <div ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete2($data,$event)">
            <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects2" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"
                 ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess2($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}" class="{{obj.class}}">
                {{obj.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div style="text-align:center">
      <button ng-click="checkAnswer()">Check Answer</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer